# Change name of property while deserializing response in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

JSON  Response from API  :

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "ResultType":"SUCCESS"
      }
   ]
}
```

After Converting to ResultClass.class  :

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "resultType":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected Output After Converting to ResultClass.class :

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "resultType":"SUCCESS"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am integrating with third party API.I want to change property name while deserializing .I have tried @JsonProperty on filed getter and setter.But the value is not reflected in field resultType.

**ResultClass.java**

```
@JsonProperty("result")
List<TestClass> result = new ArrayList<>();

public List<TestClass> getResult() {
        return result;
}

public void setResult(List<TestClass> result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

**TestClass.java**

```
@JsonProperty("ResultType")
private String resultType;

public String getResultType() {
        return resultType;
}

public void setResultType(String resultType) {
        this.resultType = resultType;
}
```

Note : I have tried JsonObject and it is working fine.I am using HttpClient and HttpResponse for making request.Jackson Version : 2.5.0

Comment: What are you actually getting in the output?. Can you add that too?

Comment: {"result":[{"ResultType":"SUCCESS"}]} and after converting {"result":[{"resultType":null}]}

Comment: I have added details @MaruthiAdithya

Comment: If you add `@JsonProperty("ResultType")` on getter and setter, what output do you get?

Comment: I test your code and every thing is ok!

Comment: Try with initializing resultType=null

Comment: getting same result @MaruthiAdithya

Comment: But not getting expected result @RahimDastar

Comment: I have tried initializing but result remains the same @TanuGarg

Comment: I test it with objectmapper and is ok

Answer (score 0):

2 Solutions are available:

**1. Make case-insensitive deserializing**

Add this feature on your object mapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

**2. Serialize and deserialize with different property names**

To change the name of the property `ResultType` to `resultType`, you should rather use both `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

public class TestClass {

    private String resultType;

    @JsonGetter("resultType")
    public String getResultType() {
        return resultType;
    }

    @JsonSetter("ResultType")
    public void setResultType(String resultType) {
        this.resultType = resultType;
    }
}
```